# Delete columns with specific row values in R

Tags: r

I would like to delete collumns with `0` in a first line:

My input:

```
NE001   NE002   NE003
  0       2       3
```

My expected output:

```
NE002    NE003
  2        3
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> foo <- data.frame("a" = c(0,1,0), b = 1:3, c = 4:6)
> foo
  a b c
1 0 1 4
2 1 2 5
3 0 3 6
> foo2 <- foo[sapply(foo, function(x) x[1] != 0)]
> foo2
  b c
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my.data <- read.table(text='

x1  x2  x3
1    0   2
3    4   5
6    8   0

', header = TRUE)

my.data

my.data[,!(my.data[1,]==0)]

  x1 x3
1  1  2
2  3  5
3  6  0
```